# Asus T3-M2NC51PV usb boot

Tags: boot, usb

I try to boot a centos netinstall image from a pendrive, without success.

I set the USB pendrive as the booting device. I tried to set how the system sees the USB device, as CDROM or as HDD and I tried all the six USB ports, but it does not work.

Is this a known hardware problem of the barebone pc? Or, I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

The trick was the following: the Asus BIOS category "removable device" was not what I needed. Instead, a usb stick is among the hard disks -- if it is put in before switching on the box -- and as such, it should be taken as the first disk, which is not the boot device order, but another list, the list of hdds.